# Matlab - A Better Way to Interpolate for a Scatter Heatmap

Tags: matlab, interpolation, heatmap

I am interpolating a scatter heatmap in MATLAB for my selective data.  The code below is on random data.  However, my data clearly show "well-defined distinct squares," making it look very choppy.  Looking for a better and improved way to interpolate over a scatter heatmap or better yet another novel way for creating a scatter heatmap?

Here is my code:

```
xd = randn(100000,1)';
yd = randn(100000,1)';

n = 100;
xi = linspace(min(xd(:)),max(xd(:)),n);
yi = linspace(min(yd(:)),max(yd(:)),n);

xr = interp1(xi,1:numel(xi),xd,'nearest')';
yr = interp1(yi,1:numel(yi),yd,'nearest')';

z = accumarray([xr yr], 1, [n n]);

figure;
imagesc(z)
 j = jet 
 j(1,:) = [ 1 1 1 ]; %
 colormap(j); 
 colorbar;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to get a smoother heatmap by using `pcolor` instead of `imagesc`, and then setting the shading mode to "interpolated", calling the command `shading interp`.